# When and how endianness naming was defined?

Tags: endianness

I've tried web search and wiki and could not find mentioning history records.

I don't buy an argument stated in [Is there any practical trick to remember the difference between big-endian and little-endian?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/142926/is-there-any-practical-trick-to-remember-the-difference-between-big-endian-and-l) that there are two ends of a sequence.

Try to ask somebody to open a book at the end and see how often the person will open at 1st page or at least ask in response: "first of last page?"

So why "little-endianness" means to start (lower address in memory) with least significant byte? Who and when decided on such naming?

Comment: I found this answer on [Retrocomputing Stackexchange](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/2653): *Endianness as a byte-order term goes back to Danny Cohen’s On Holy Wars and a Plea for Peace, published as Internet Experiment Note 137 in April 1980 and again in IEEE Computer Magazine in October 1981."*

Comment: @DocBrown, good read and seems reasonable (that first byte to send is the original question), however the article' date is `April 1`, so it casts doubt of its validity as a reference.

Comment: I don't think this matters - even if the terms were intended to be funny, maybe motivated by the date, it is still an official publication where the terms occurs - and I guess it is not unlikely it was the first publication. Cohen refered to "Gulliver's travels" and tells us in the Appendix the terms were intentionally made in parallel to "Lilliput" and "Blefuscu".

Comment: I don't see why you object to the two ends of the sequence, that's common in English. (Near/far end, east/west end, long/short end, ...)

Comment: Look at an ordinary decimal number, like 1234. There, in terms of what contributes to the value, '1' is the most significant digit (because it represents thousands, and if you changed it, it would affect the value the most). It's the "big end" of the number. Similarly '4' is the least significant digit (it represents ones, and if you changed it, it would affect the value the least). It's the "little end". You can transfer the same concept to a sequence of bytes. In decimal numbers, each digit can be one of 9 values. In byte sequences, each "digit" can be one of 256 values.

Answer (score 4):

> When and how endianness naming was defined?

I think Doc covered this part quite well with a comment:

> I found this answer on [Retrocomputing Stackexchange](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/2653/771): Endianness as a byte-order term goes back to Danny Cohen’s On Holy Wars and a Plea for Peace, published as Internet Experiment Note 137 in April 1980 and again in IEEE Computer Magazine in October 1981.
>
> [Doc Brown](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/450132/when-and-how-endianness-naming-was-defined/450142#comment990773_450132)

I did dig up [Danny Cohen's On Holy Wars and a Plea for Peace](https://www.rfc-editor.org/ien/ien137.txt). According to [C2 wiki](https://wiki.c2.com/?OnHolyWarsAndaPleaForPeace) this is where the “big/little endian” terms were introduced.

Page 13 has a beautiful ascii art diagram showing the four ways endianness can stir up bits. Be aware they only all apply when bits are addressable. Such as on the wire, over the air, on paper, but not in memory where bits are not addressable. In memory, order 2 and 4 are the same (big endian) and order 1 and 3 (little endian) are the same. In memory, where bits can't be addressed, you might as well replace each pair of slashes with a dot.

But I'll address your skepticism.

> I don't buy ... that there are two ends of a sequence.

The problem here is all about assumptions.

To make sense of endianness naming you must accept some conventional assumptions.

- Addresses start small
- Numbers get bigger as their significance grows
- End, as in, of a stick

Only with these arbitrary assumptions in place does starting to eat an egg at either the big or small end make sense as an analogy.

> Try to ask somebody to open a book at the end and see how often the person will open at 1st page or at least ask in response: "first of last page?"

Ask someone to hold an egg by the end and they wont know if you mean the big or small end because, just like a stick, it has two ends.

The problem here is the word "end" is overloaded. It has multiple meanings:

> 1. a final part of something, especially a period of time, an activity, or a story. "the end of the year"
> 2. the furthest or most extreme part or point of something.
>
> [define end](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+end) Google - Oxford Languages

You assumed meaning 1. But meaning 2 is being used here.

Ask a person from Japan to open a book to "the last page" and they will open the left cover because they address the pages in their books in the opposite direction westerners do.

Now sure that's just page numbers but addresses in memory don't always grow as you advance. For example, the stack pointer address gets bigger when you push. But the heap pointer gets smaller as you add to the heap. Why? Because they're trying to share the same fixed memory and having them grow towards each other from either end keeps them separate.

The address starting small is just another assumption.

As for numbers, yes, they get bigger as their significance grows, so long as the number isn't zero. Let's not even get into negative numbers.

Therefor,

**Big Endian** means start (lowest address) with the big (most significant) end (side) of the number.

And

**Little Endian** means start (lowest address) with the little (least significant) end (side) of the number.

Give us all that and the names can make sense. Take any of that away and yes it just becomes silly.

<sub>I prefer my eggs scrambled.</sub>

Comment: I just remember that littleendian has lots of letters in common with Intel, so Intel processors are littleendian. And on Intel processors hex dumps are wrong, 0x12345678 is displayed as 78 56 34 12. And bigendian / littleendian store the big byte / little byte at the start, not at the end.